# Why are perfect graphs called perfect?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, terminology, graph-colouring

Sorry, if this is a naive question, but I could not find the justification in any of the major text books like Bondy-Murty, Diestel or West. [Perfect graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph) have many beautiful properties, but what is the single reason they are called perfect? Or is it just a aesthetic preference by Berge?

Comment: Presumably, he originally called them *parfait* and not *perfect.* It does mean almost the same thing. Possibly some French speaker here could tell us whether *parfait* in French is slightly less absolute in meaning than *perfect* in English.

Comment: The meaning is exactly the same in our language as in yours.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

perfect graphs were first motivated by information transmission theory originating with Shannon ie [Shannon Capacity of graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShannonCapacity.html). they are called "perfect" by Berge because they can be used to model a noiseless or "perfect" information channel wrt transposition errors in transmission called "confounding". from intro in [3] which also has a very detailed history in the 1st chapter cowritten by Berge.

> When Claude Berge defined perfect graphs in 1961, he was motivated by a very practical problem: how do we maximize the rate at which information is sent through a (noisy) transmission channel while avoiding the introduction of errors because of the physical imperfections of the system?

[1] C. Berge, The history of the perfect graphs, Southeast Asian Bull. Math.
20, No.1 (1996) 5-10.
[2] C. Berge, Motivations and history of some of my conjectures, Discrete Mathematics
165-166 (1997) 61-70.
[3] [Perfect Graphs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471489700) by Jorge L. Ramírez-Alfonsín (Editor), Bruce A. Reed (Editor), J.L.R. Alfonsin (Author). Wiley. Ch1, Origins and Genesis by Berge & Ramírez-Alfonsín

Comment: I suspect this answer could use more explanation. For perfect graphs, the single-symbol zero-error capacity (encoding the information without using block codes) is equal to the asymptotic zero-error capacity. Thus, you can easily calculate the zero-error capacity, and it is obtainable using the simplest possible code. One of Lovász's [celebrated results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovász_number) was calculating this capacity for the five-cycle, the simplest non-perfect graph. And unless progress has been made in the last couple of years, we still don't know what it is for the seven-cycle.

Comment: I like the succinctness of the answer, in conjunction with the citations.  This is a topic on the periphery for me, and this short answer is quite useful as an intro to a complex subject.