# Hardest known natural problem in P?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms

I wonder, what is (currently) the largest number $k$, such that a *natural* problem is known with the following properties:

1. An $O(n^k)$ algorithm has been already found for the problem.
2. For any fixed $\epsilon>0$ no $O(n^{k-\epsilon})$ algorithm is known for the same problem. (Note that a faster algorithm $may$ exist, just it is not known yet, so I am not looking for a proven lower bound.)
3. The problem description itself does not depend on $k$. (This condition is needed to exclude parametrized cases like "find a clique of size $k$ in an input graph, for a constant $k$.")

In a sense, such a problem might qualify as the *hardest, known, natural, problem* in $\bf P$ (regarding the exponent of the fastest known algorithm).

Comment: Try this maybe? http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/6660/1800

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that post. It has plenty of interesting answers.

Comment: Another related post is http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13202/decision-problems-in-mathsfp-without-fast-algorithms

Comment: matrix multiplication exponent could fit as an answer?

Answer (score 27):

The [AKS Primality testing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) may be a good candidate, where the best algorithm currently known version of the algorithm has $\tilde{O}(n^6)$ running time.  See [Primality testing with Gaussian periods](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/aks041411.pdf) (Lenstra and Pomerance).

Answer (score 16):

How bout [finding two disjoint shortest paths](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166218X97001212/1-s2.0-S0166218X97001212-main.pdf?_tid=11728ab4-be80-11e3-9e7c-00000aacb361&acdnat=1396894481_d7c17dcda37aaade0c9ed6c63e7c7bc7), which has a runtime of $O(|V|^8)$?

Also, $O(|V|^{12}\cdot |E|)$ algorithm [is known](http://www.ii.uib.no/~martinv/Papers/ISinP5free.pdf) for independent set in $P_5$-free graphs.

Answer (score 13):

[perfect graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph) appear to be fundamental and therefore "natural" to complexity theory/math in many ways. the [recognition algorithm](http://integer.tepper.cmu.edu/webpub/BergeAlg.pdf) runs in time $O(|V(G)|^9)$. it seems possible there are other "natural" or "fundamental" graph classes that take longer to recognize and are still in P.

Comment: note perfect graphs are based on optimizing/maximizing the [Shannon (communication) capacity of graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShannonCapacity.html); see also [why are perfect graphs called perfect](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/)